# Issue with registry entry in one .wxs file to create both 32 bit and 64 bit installer

Tags: wix3.7

Here is my script:

```
<DirectoryRef Id="TARGETDIR">
      <!--for 64 bit platform-->
      <?if $(sys.BUILDARCH)="x64"?>
        <Component Id="RegistryEntries64" Guid="EFC1C5ED-0BC8-4B52-943A-BFF5F3136B4F" Win64="yes">
          <RegistryKey Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBCINST.INI\ODBC Drivers">
            <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="$(var.ProductNameForRegistyEntry)" Value="Installed" KeyPath="yes"/>
          </RegistryKey>
          <RegistryKey Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBCINST.INI\$(var.ProductNameForRegistyEntry)">
           <-------/>
          </RegistryKey>
          <RemoveFolder Id="RegistryEntries64" On="uninstall"/>
        </Component>
      <?else?>
        <!--for 32 bit platform-->
        <Component Id="RegistryEntries86" Guid="E37BE3EF-1979-4C56-A768-2D6B6AB99870" Win64="no">
            <RegistryKey Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\ODBC\ODBCINST.INI\ODBC Drivers">
              <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="$(var.ProductNameForRegistyEntry)" Value="Installed"/>
            </RegistryKey>
            <RegistryKey Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\ODBC\ODBCINST.INI\$(var.ProductNameForRegistyEntry)">
              <----->
            </RegistryKey>
          <RemoveFolder Id="RegistryEntries86" On="uninstall"/>
         </Component>
       <?endif?>

    </DirectoryRef>
```

With this script the 32 bit installer created (x86 platform select in Visual studio 2015) working fine on 64 bit operating system machine, registry entry getting created inside WOW6432Node, basically this is 32 bit installer to install on 64 bit machine, so that user can install both 64 bit and 32 bit installer on 64 bit machine but on 32 bit operating system, registry entry should be inside SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBCINST.INI\ODBC Drivers. On 32 bit machine Get-OdbcDriver command doesn't returns the driver in the list.
platform variable is not suggested by Wix itself
sys.BUILDARCH fetch the target platform type.
Do I need to write a separate script for 32 bit operating system machine, where I will give registry entry SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBCINST.INI\ODBC Drivers? Or there some other solution ?
I look so many stackoverflow post and others posts over internet but nothing related to this I could find. 
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create a separate script for that. One possible solution could be you define another variable (i.e Installer_x86_x86) and based on its value you can create 32-bit installer for both 64-bit and 32-bit OS.

```
 <?if $(var.Installer_x86_x86)="no"?>
              <RegistryKey Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\ODBC\ODBCINST.INI\ODBC Drivers">
                <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="$(var.ProductNameForRegistyEntry)" Value="Installed"/>
              </RegistryKey>
              <RegistryKey Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\ODBC\ODBCINST.INI\$(var.ProductNameForRegistyEntry)">
                <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="Description" Value="TIBCO ComputeDB ODBC Driver" />

              </RegistryKey>
             <?else?>
              <RegistryKey Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBCINST.INI\ODBC Drivers">
                <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="$(var.ProductNameForRegistyEntry)" Value="Installed"/>
              </RegistryKey>
              <RegistryKey Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBCINST.INI\$(var.ProductNameForRegistyEntry)">
                <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="Description" Value="TIBCO ComputeDB ODBC Driver" />

              </RegistryKey>
            <?endif?>
```

It would be better if you create a .wxi file and put all  your variables into it and include it in your .wxs file, so that it will be easy for you change variable value before creating the installer